# Complex dot product

Tags: complex-analysis

I know that the complex dot product is defined as $\boldsymbol{a}\cdot\boldsymbol{b}=\sum_{i}a_ib_i^*$. Is there a standard name for the operator $\boldsymbol{a}\cdot\boldsymbol{b}=\sum_{i}\mathcal{I}\{a_ib_i^*\}$?

Comment: If $\mathcal{I}$ denotes the imaginary part, that's not an inner product.

Comment: Replaced inner product with operator.

Comment: This is essentially the [standard symplectic form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplectic_vector_space#Standard_symplectic_space) on $\mathbb{C}^n$.

Comment: Could you please expand on this, I do not even know what a standard symplectic form is?

Comment: The known inner product on $\mathbb{C}$ is $a.b=\sum_{I=0}^n a_i\bar{b}_i$